# Freeform Pro Submit Issue

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, email-contact-form

I have a simple contact form built using FreeForm Pro (free version). Everything on the front end works as normal but when submitting the form I get directed to http://sxps.co.uk/?ACT=22 (not the actual site URL sxps.co.uk) No submission is recorded to the form either.

Any ideas why I get directed to this page and no information is recorded? Code below.

```
{exp:freeform:form
                            form_id="1"
                            required="email"
                            return="contact-us/thank-you"
                            notify_admin="yes"


                        }

                            <label for="full_name">Name:</label>
                            {freeform:field:full_name} 

                          <label for="telephone">Phone Number:</label>
                            {freeform:field:telephone_number} 

                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                            {freeform:field:email} 


                             <label>Message:</label> 
                            {freeform:field:user_message}


                             {freeform:submit}

                        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see if you have any javascript errors on the form page?

Answer (score 1):

check your general config settings. 
Are you removing the index.php file?
When it gets stuck here: http://sxps.co.uk/?ACT=22 
Try changing it to: http://sxps.co.uk/index.php?ACT=22 or set index.php as the site's index page in general config.
If that runs, then we know FreeForm is running.
Then we can look elsewhere.

Comment: I just checked a couple of my installations and the action for all is mydomain.com/?ACT=XX